# SketchFlow Template for Windows Phone doesn't work with Blend for Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone-8-sdk, expression-blend-5

I am trying to use the SketchFlow Template for Windows Phone (http://wp7sketchflow.codeplex.com) with Blend for Visual Studio 2013 and when I try to create a project with the template I get this error:

> New Project failed. Could not find file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Blend
> Preview\ProjectTemplates\en\CSharp\WindowsPhone\WindowsPhone\csWindowsPhonePrototype.zip[ControlLibrary\AssemblyInfo.cs].

I have looked inside the directory and the file does file exist. Does anyone have a solution? The only other stuff I found is http://wp7sketchflow.codeplex.com/discussions/429011.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also posted to that thread with a solution. Which I will also add here.

I've posted a fix for using this template with SketchFlow that ships in Blend/VS2013 (may work in 2012 but I didn't test).

Please read my instructions I've tried to be a clear as possible.

1. You WILL need to download and install the SketchFlowWP7.zip file from this codeplex (I also provide a copy in the link below).
2. Extract SketchFlowWP7.zip and run the SketchFlowWP7.msi to install.
3. When it prompts where to install choose the path to your copy of Blend. For instance for VS2013 it's default path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend"
4. Next you will need to navigate down into the following folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\ProjectTemplates\en\CSharp\WindowsPhone"
5. Here you will find a file names csWindowsPhonePrototype.zip, delete it. Yes really delete it, you are going to be replacing it's contents in the next steps.
6. Download the csWindowsPhonePrototype.zip from the following linkg - http://sdrv.ms/1hED9Cm
7. Extract the contents of csWindowsPhonePrototype.zip and you will have a folder called csWindowsPhonePrototype
8. Move the extracted folder into the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\ProjectTemplates\en\CSharp\WindowsPhone" directory. PLEASE make sure that you don't have a folder called csWindowsPhonePrototype inside of it, if you do it's that child folder you need to move.
9. Now when you fire up Blend you should see an option for SketchFlow for Windows Phone.